# I tried to download the new version of Rstudio, I already downloaded the new R

Tags: r, rstudio

[image]

I deleted all old versions and cleared the trash. I then redownloaded Innocent and Trusting for R and tried to download the new Studio but I keep getting the same error once I click it in my applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to delete the previous version. On Mac, you need to first, download the new R version and install it. Then, download the R-Studio/Posit new version and install it. After that, open R, as always!

(Everything without coding, do it from the webpages!)

1. R: https://cran.rstudio.com/
2. R-Studio/Posit: https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/

Comment: Hey y’all thank you so much! I’ll try again. Did you see the picture I uploaded? That is what’s popping up after downloading the new Rstudio.